# How to determine whether given language is regular or not(by just looking at the language)?

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, computation-theory, dfa, pumping-lemma

Is there any trick to guess if a language is regular by just looking at the language?

In order to choose proof methods, I have to have some hypothesis at first. Do you know any hints/patterns required to reduce time consumption in solving long questions?

For instance, in order not to spend time on pumping lemma, when language is regular and I don't want to construct DFA/grammar.

For example:

```
1. L={w ε {a,b}*/no of a in (w) < no of b in (w)}
2. L={a^nb^m/n,m>=0}
```

How to tell which is regular by just looking at the above examples??

Answer (score 1):

In general, when looking at a language, a good rule of thumb for whether the language is regular or not is to think of a program that can read a string and answer the question "is this string in the language?"

To write such a program, do you need to store some arbitrary value in a variable or is the program's state (that is, the combination of all possible variables' values) limited to some finite fixed number of possibilities? If the language can be recognized by a program that only needs a fixed number of variables that can only have a fixed number of values, then you've got a regular language. If not, then not.

Using this, I can see that the first language is not regular, but the second language is. In the first language, I need to remember how many `a`s I've seen, and how many `b`s. (Or at the very least, I need to keep track of (# of `a`s) - (# of `b`s), and accept if the string ends while that count is negative). At the same time, there's no limit on the number of `a`s, so this count could go arbitrarily large.

In the second language, I don't care what `n` and `m` are at all. So with the second language, my program would just keep track of "have I seen at least one `b` yet?" to make sure we don't have any `a` characters that occur after the first `b`. (So, one variable with only two values - true or false)

So one way to make language 1 into a regular language is to change it to be:

```
1. L={w ∈ {a,b}*/no of a in (w) < no of b in (w), and no of a in (w) < 100}
```

Now I don't need to keep track of the number of `a`s that I've seen once I hit 100 (since then I know automatically that the string isn't in the language), and likewise with the number of `b`s - once I hit 100, I can stop counting because I know that'll be enough unless the number of `a`s is itself too large.

One common case you should watch out for with this is when someone asks you about languages where "number of `a`s is a multiple of 13" or "*w* ∈ {0,1}* and *w* is the binary representation of a multiple of 13". With these, it might seem like you need to keep track of the whole number to make the determination, but in fact you don't - in both cases, you only need to keep a variable that can count from 0 to 12. So watch out for "multiple of"-type languages. (And the related "is odd" or "is even" or "is 1 more than a multiple of 13")

Other mathematical properties though - for example, *w* ∈ {0,1}* and *w* is the binary representation of a perfect square - will result in non-regular languages.